# MaterializeCSS no muestra los íconos

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, materialize

Estoy desarrollando un *Landing Page* con la librería [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) dentro del menú quiero mostrar un ícono con `<i class="materials-icons"></i>` pero no los carga.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="es">
          <head>
               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
               <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection"/>
          </head>
          <body>
               <nav>
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                         <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i> SoftDev</a>
                         <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">refresh</i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
               </nav>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.js"></script>
          </body>
     </html>
```

Ya revisé las referencias de los archivos *CSS* y *JavaScript* y están funcionando correctamente, no sé cuál sea el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No has agregado la referencia a la fuente de iconos de Materialize CSS.
Luego de los Scripts agrega esta etiqueta:

```
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Se me habia escapado eso. No lo vi en la documentación. Gracias @michael-traña